# Stop button losing focus when contextmenu event fires

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom-events

I've got a react application that has a need for a piece of content to play when a button is held down and then stop when the button is released.

I've implemented this by creating a helper to handle detecting a longpress, when `onMouseDown` or `onTouchStart` is fired then it plays, when `onMouseUp`, `onMouseLeave` or `onTouchEnd` fires it stops. This all works perfectly on desktop. The issues comes when we take a look at mobile, mobile treats a long press as a right click in the desktop and tries to launch a contextmenu or highlight an element/piece of text, to deal with this I've added the following css:

```css
touch-action: none;
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
```

and the following Javascript:

```js
window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
};
```

This works as expected in the sense that the contextmenu doesn't display, however the button that is being held does lose focus, meaning that the content continues to play and the `onMouseUp`, `onMouseLeave` or `onTouchEnd` events never fire unless you tap somewhere on the button or screen again, I've tried solutions like reapplying the focus to the button during the `onContextMenu` event however that doesn't work either.

Comment: Please do try this codepen https://codepen.io/p2pdops/pen/RwpEbxP I'm not sure if this would solve the issue, but it's working as expected for me (tested in desktop & android emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Mobile user agents do not consider a long touch as a right click when the target element is a `button` (because there are no mobile compatible actions on a button, other than just click). I suggest you to verify that the button you're talking about is an actual `button`.

```js
const button  = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { this.classList.add('red') });
button.addEventListener('touchstart', function() { this.classList.add('red') });

button.addEventListener('mouseup', function() { this.classList.remove('red') });
button.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() { this.classList.remove('red') });
button.addEventListener('touchend', function() { this.classList.remove('red') });
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This link does trigger a context menu on a long touch</a> <button>This button doesn’t</button>
```

If that does not answer your question, please add the actual HTML code.

Comment: Hey Guerric, you're correct however a long touch on a mobile user agent does still launch a context menu, the way you launch that menu on mobile might not actually fire a left click, but you still end up with a context menu, that's what I was trying to communicate

Comment: I will still reward you the bounty, because you're the only person who actually attempted to answer the question, but I won't accept this answer as it turns out the answer to my problem was something different

Answer (score 0):

When using this on desktop clicking my mouse would fire the mousedown event, which is expected, when using this on mobile it was firing two events at the same time, meaning when it would fire touchend it would also fire mouseleave or mouseup, i'm unsure why this was happening but to resolve my issue I just conditionally added the event listeners, so for mobile I now only add event listeners for touchstart, touchend and touchcancel.